# GRE math prep question

Tags: calculus

How can I solve $\int_{0}^{x}(1-e^{-t})\, f(t)\, dt = xe^{2x}$ for $f(x)$. Problem from [here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-prepare-for-the-GRE-Mathematics-Subject-test).

I tried solving $(1-e^{-t})\, f(t) \left\rvert \right._{t=x}= \frac{d}{dx} x e^{2x}$, but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why didn’t it work?

Answer (score 3):

Applying the Fundamental theorem of Calculus should work. 
Just take the derivative with respect to $x$ on both sides and apply the first part of the Theorem.

Solving for $f(x)$ gives you $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{2x}(2x+1)}{1-e^{-x}}$.
Notice that you can treat the case $x=0$ first on which the identity becomes trivial.